# Mac OS X printing "different" colors than Windows 10

Tags: macos, windows-10, printing, color-profiles

I'm encountering a situation in a workplace where Mac systems (OS X - El Capitan 10.11.6) are printing colors to a Xerox WorkCentre 7835 correctly from all applications, but all Windows 10 machines (using the Xerox printer driver) are printing different colors.

I can confirm that this isn't application specific - whether it is Adobe PDF or Microsoft Word, the Windows 10 machines are printing the "wrong" colors. Is there something in the way OS X and Windows 10 handle print jobs that would cause a discrepancy?

The Windows 10 people are product managers trying to print off packaging art from their graphic designers and the whole office is stymied (and frustrated) by the Windows 10 machines going "off brand" with their colors.

Attached is a sample of how an RGB blue color that I specified in a Word document came from the same printer (and same file) but in different shades of blue. The discrepancy is more noticeable in person, but I assure you it's there!

The only other thing I can think to add is that when I was poking around in Windows 10 printing preferences, the driver was clearly labelled as Xerox. But I didn't see anything similar on the Mac - the OS seemed to be providing its own driver config interface (or at least wrapping the Xerox drivers in the OS X look/feel).

[image: Color documents showing discrepancy]

Comment: I poked around and found a link that might help diagnose the issue: http://support.datacolor.com/index.php?/Knowledgebase/Article/View/1234/37/how-to-disable-color-management-at-the-printer-driver-level-how-can-i-make-sure-that-color-management-is-disabled-completely-in-my-printer-driver-prior-to-printing-the-spyder3print-sr-color-targets-from-within-the-spyder3printsr-application

Comment: Additionally, in Windows try searching under "Colour Management" to see if any profile is being loaded (Make sure the dropdown box has your printer selected!).

Comment: I found that, actually! But no colour profiles had been loaded for the printer.

Comment: Windows has never handled colour correctly, whereas OSX has, but loading the printer's colour profile should help. Load the printer's ICM file into Windows\System32\Spool\drivers\color

Comment: Thanks @hdhondt - I didn't know that printers had colour profiles that could be loaded. (Obviously I knew about drivers). I'll give this a shot! Consider adding it as an answer I can accept, if you'd like.

Answer (score 1):

To display of print colours with any degree of accuracy, both Windows and OSX rely on device colour profiles (.ICC or .ICM) files. These files need to be installed for each device.

In OSX, [ColorSync](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2313/_index.html) allows the Mac to match colours on all connected devices. It requires the printer's ICC file to be installed in Library > Colorsync > Profiles.

In Windows, on the other hand, colour management is done from the Control Panel. In Win10, the easiest way to find it is to type "Colour Management" into Cortana. You can select the profiles for both the display and the printer. The files must be installed in C:\Windows\System32\Spool\drivers\color'

Even if the correct profiles are installed and selected, there is no guarantee that OSX and Windows will print the same colours. One of the fundamental reasons is that the conversion is from a 3 variable model (RGB) to 4 or more variables (CMYK). As a result there are infinitely conversions possible for every colour.

ColorSync also manages input devices such as canners and cameras, Windows does not. Both will use default profiles if no device file is selected. These defaults are different in OSX and Windows.

In both cases, but especially in Windows, it is preferable to use "colour aware" applications such as Adobe InDesign or PhotoShop. Applications like Word do not really understand colour, and the output can only ever be approximate.

Comment: Wow. What a fantastic answer. Thanks @hdhont! I'll see if I can get the profiles loaded onto my client's Windows machines.